# Make "automatic" corrections on failed groups matching

Tags: c#, regex

I've got a regular expression like this:

```
([A-Z]{2})([0-9]*)([A-Z]{1})
```

And with this I'm going to verify codes like:

```
MD0133776311I
```

So, when I've got "wrong codes", I'm wondering the best method to make corrections automatically, based on some simple rules that's depending on which "matching group" .

For example, if I've got a code like this:

```
M**1**0133776311I
```

regexp fails because first two chars are not literal (first matching group), and so the program should be apply a change to the second string character replacing `1` with, for example, `I`.

What's the best manner to do this, exploit at best regular expressions?

Comment: Regular expressions can't guess what you mean. :) You need to determine and code the rules you want to apply. Do you always want to replace the second character, if it's a digit, with capital `i` for example?

Comment: For example, if I've got a "1" as second digit, I want always to replace it with "I".
I've got matching rules like "Two literals, then some number, and literal as last char", and basing on other simple rules, I've got to "change" some chars to make the code uniforming to the initial regexp.

Comment: Yes, but that's an example. You can do that with something like `Regex.Replace("^[A-Z]{1}[1]", "(1)I")` What if it's a 2?

Comment: If 2 for example "S". Please, read also my edit to the previous comment ;)

Comment: Well then read my previous comment, you need to code those rules. Code doesn't work with examples, you need to be explicit.

Comment: Another thing: At the moment the best way for make a good job is making a software in which this kind of rules are parametric.

Comment: Uhm... I'll try to convert every single "group matching " in a single regexp and apply replace based on rules.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it using a replacement map, replacing the character at index 1 if the given code doesn't start with two letters:

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public class Test
{
    private static string[] productCodes = new[] { 
        "MD0133776311I",
        "M10133776311I",
        "M20133776311I"
    };

    private static Dictionary<char, char> replacementMap = new Dictionary<char, char> {
        { '1', 'I' },
        { '2', 'S' },
    };

    private static Regex startsWithTwoLettersRegex = new Regex("^([A-Z]{2})");

    public static void Main()
    {
        foreach (var code in productCodes)
        {
            Console.Write("{0} -> ", code);
            if (!startsWithTwoLettersRegex.Match(code).Success)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(FixProductCode(code));
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("OK!");   
            }
        }
    }

    static string FixProductCode(string code)
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(code);
        sb[1] = replacementMap[code[1]];
        return sb.ToString();
    }
}
```

Outputs:

```
MD0133776311I -> OK!
M10133776311I -> MI0133776311I
M20133776311I -> MS0133776311I
```

See [example on IdeOne](http://ideone.com/89oSWW).

I'm sure you can mold this into something more flexible, but like I said in my comments, a regex can't guess what you mean. You need to be explicit in code, and manually fixing characters at set positions in the string.

Note this won't fix the *first* character if that isn't a letter, nor will it check the remainder of the code.